# extracting information about outlink of url in nutch

Tags: nutch

I am quite new to nutch. I have crawled a site successfully using nutch 1.2 and extracted segment dump by **readseg** command but issue is that dump contains lot of information other than url and outlinks also if i want to analyse it, manual approach needs to be adopted. 
It would be really great if there is any utiltiy, plugin which export link with out links in machine readable format like csv or sql.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will have to write your own application to do this. You can provide additional flags to remove unecessary data.

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20readseg

check here for what flags can be used to reduce the data.

alternatively writing your own application using the hadoop FS library would be better, and then to extract the information directly programatically.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile